# Any way to validate Schema.org JSON-LD before publishing?

Tags: validation, json-ld, schema.org

I have a site with a lot of data, and I'm dynamically building JSON-LD data that I think is Schema.org correct. I can't find a dead-on example on Schema.org, and it will take forever if I have to publish the content live, then wait for Google to say there's a problem, then re-attempt it, then wait again, etc.

This is an example of what I'd like to validate:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "TravelAction",
    "agent": {
        "type": "Person",
        "name": "John Schmuckatelly"
    }
    "fromLocation": {
        "@type": "Country",
        "name": Curacao",
        "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
        "latitude": 12.05",
        "longitude": -68.81667"
    }
    "toLocation": {
        "@type": "Country",
        "name":Aruba
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can execute the json locally and then copy and paste the HTML into Google's Webmaster Tools Structured data tool. No direct json method will exist since this isn't not what is displayed in the browser, the output is.. so just setup the json to output completely and then verify it,.

Comment: I tried the web master tool using Schema.org's own example (http://schema.org/TravelAction), pasting the script tag in, and it's not showing any structured data. Regarding "executing the json", the json data is just data sitting in a script tag that google/whomever should be able to read. Not much else I think I need to do with it?

Comment: Google updated their link to the [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool), so try pasting it there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Tool from *Yandex*

- The "[Structured data validator](http://webmaster.yandex.com/microtest.xml)" supports JSON-LD.

  Alexander Shubin (working for *Yandex*) [wrote](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/2013Dec/0005.html):

  > Pls, take into account that in order to check JSON-LD you need to put it in  tag (since this is how it should be embedded into html).
  >   E.g.,
  >
  > ```
  > <script type="application/ld+json">{
  >   "@context":"http://schema.org",
  >   "@type" : "CommunicateAction",
  >  "instrument" : {
  >     "@type" : "EmailMessage"
  >   },
  >   "handler" : {
  >     "@type" : "WebHandler",
  >    "url" : "http://www.example.com/send_email"
  >   }
  > }
  > </script>
  > ```

#### Tools from *Google*

- The "[Email Markup Tester](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/)" supports JSON-LD, which could also be used for JSON-LD intended for web pages.

  Justin Boyan (working for *Google*) [wrote](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/2013Dec/0084.html):

  > While Google's Structured Data Testing Tool doesn't support JSON-LD, we do
  >   have an Email Markup Tester http://g.co/EmailMarkupTester that does --
  >   tailored, as you might guess, to the use cases supported by
  >   Gmail<https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/reference/formats/json-ld>.
  >   Still, it's possible to paste in arbitrary JSON-LD (in a script tag, as
  >   with Yandex's tool).
- **Update 2015-01:** Google has [released](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2015/01/new-structured-data-testing-tool.html) a new Structured Data Testing Tool with "Expanded support for the JSON-LD markup syntax":

  https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/

Comment: The Yandex tool seemed to work out the best for me, and after an hour of tweaking->copy->paste->retweak I finally got it looking good. Thanks so much for the help. The Google tool seems to only validate certain types (events, local businesses, etc) which in my case can't really do much.

Comment: @radpin: Google has released a new tool (see update in my answer), maybe this is of interest to you.

Comment: Google updated their link to the SDTT again: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

Comment: If you're using TypeScript, you can integrate some form of Schema.org validation into your dev toolchain with typings like https://github.com/google/schema-dts